# Windows Update error 0x80243004 without Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-update, windows-embedded-7

So the resolution for this error is to change settings in Windows Taskbar, but, if you've created a Windows Embedded image with the package `Command Prompt Shell with Custom Shell Support`, there is no Windows explorer, or Task bar, leaving me unable to use Windows Update.

Is there any way I can resolve this error if explorer/a task bar is not available?

Comment: 0x80243004 means WU_E_TRAYICON_FAILURE  - A failure occurred when trying to create an icon in the taskbar notification area.  so Windows update requires the taskbar

Comment: Right but I find it hard to believe it's literally impossible to use Windows update if you don't have the explorer shell.. There must be a workaround @magicandre1981

Comment: this i properly the taskbar icon, telling you to reboot in 10 minutes or delay it. you can install the Updates MSU with DISM, this should work without taskbar.

Answer (score -1):

Right Click the task bar > Properties, click Customize >>uncheck the box "Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar" and explicitly tell Windows Update to "Show icon and notifications"

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Ramdas